# JSON to php array conversion

Tags: php, arrays, json, jira-rest-api

Here is a JSON file from JIRA [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-use-rest-api-to-add-issue-links-in-jira-issues-939932271.html) -

```
{
   "update":{
      "issuelinks": [
         {
            "add":{
               "type":{
                  "name":"Blocks",
                  "inward":"is blocked by",
                  "outward":"blocks"
               },
               "outwardIssue":{
                  "key":"Test-123"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I am trying to convert this to php array to make the api call from a PHP application i am working on -

```
data = array(
    'update' => array(
        'issuelinks' => array(
            array (
                'add' => array(
                    'type' => array(
                        'name' => 'Blocks',
                        'inward' => 'is blocked by',
                        'outward' => 'blocks',
                        ),
                'outwardIssue' => array (
                        'key' => 'Test-123',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

When I send the request from Postman using the JSON file, the request goes through, but if I make a request using my php app, it drops without giving me any error.

Is this because of big bracket, '[' in json file? (I have used double php arrays to replace it)

Comment: Your code looks correct. When I use `json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` it looks just like the original JSON.

Comment: You can also use `var_export(json_decode($original_json, true));` to see how to create an equivalent array.

Comment: The problem is probably with how you're making the request, not the JSON. Post the rest of the code.